# Is there any way to enable the ringer ONLY for a particular caller/group of callers?

Tags: ringtone

Is there any way or app that will take a phone that is normally on silent/vibrate, and enable the ringer for a selected group of callers?

My wife is notorious for leaving her phone on silent, and there have been several emergencies where I could not reach her because she couldn't hear/feel her phone ringing. I'd like to have a way so that when I or any other family members call her, her phone will ring, even though she has it on silent/vibrate.

I've read that the app "Locale" may work, but they offer no demo for their app, and I'd prefer not to spend 10$ if it doesn't work. Their dev hasn't responded to the email I've sent.

Any ideas or methods would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [WhoIsIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handyandy.whoisit)?

> - Setup different ringtones and vibration patterns for SMS, MMS, Google Talk, Google Voice, and K-9 for each contact